# why I can't install dlib correctly in Anaconda or python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, dlib

I tried every method to install dlib in anaconda and python but everytime when I tried to import it I get this response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\malle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dlib.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = dlib.vectors()
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'vectors'
```

can u help me please ? I use python 3.6.8

Comment: we'll need more information about how you tried installing. You need to have a c/c++ compiler to properly install, which is a bit unique amongst most python libraries. Most libraries provide pre-compiled binaries instead. On windows you can get the compiler and development toolchains via visual studio

Comment: yes I tried with pip install cmake also with conda install -c conda-forge dlib and every method but nothings worked!

Comment: do you have `cmake` and `msvc` compiler (or some other c/c++ compiler) installed and working? you probably got error messages when calling setup.py

Comment: cmake is not from pip. the easiest way to get cmake is from visual studio installer

Comment: try to type `cmake -h` in a windows command prompt (or powershell). Do you get a big block of text describing how the tool works, or is the command not found?

Comment: this is what I get when I typed cmake -h :

Comment: ok, so you have cmake... now go look in your `site-packages` folder and look for `_dlib_pybind11.xxxx.pyd` (xxxx indicates the python version targeted at compile time. Make sure it matches the version of python you're using). if it's not there you would have probably gotten an `ImportError`, but make sure it's a relatively large file (mine is ~8Mb). Try importing that instead of dlib too... It may give you a more informative error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Windows\system32>cmake -h
Usage

  cmake [options] <path-to-source>
  cmake [options] <path-to-existing-build>
  cmake [options] -S <path-to-source> -B <path-to-build>

Specify a source directory to (re-)generate a build system for it in the
current working directory.  Specify an existing build directory to
re-generate its build system.

Options
  -S <path-to-source>          = Explicitly specify a source directory.
  -B <path-to-build>           = Explicitly specify a build directory.
  -C <initial-cache>           = Pre-load a script to populate the cache.
  -D <var>[:<type>]=<value>    = Create or update a cmake cache entry.
  -U <globbing_expr>           = Remove matching entries from CMake cache.
  -G <generator-name>          = Specify a build system generator.
  -T <toolset-name>            = Specify toolset name if supported by
                                 generator.
  -A <platform-name>           = Specify platform name if supported by
                                 generator.
  -Wdev                        = Enable developer warnings.
  -Wno-dev                     = Suppress developer warnings.
  -Werror=dev                  = Make developer warnings errors.
  -Wno-error=dev               = Make developer warnings not errors.
  -Wdeprecated                 = Enable deprecation warnings.
  -Wno-deprecated              = Suppress deprecation warnings.
  -Werror=deprecated           = Make deprecated macro and function warnings
                                 errors.
  -Wno-error=deprecated        = Make deprecated macro and function warnings
                                 not errors.
  --preset=<preset>            = Specify a configure preset.
  --list-presets               = List available presets.
  -E                           = CMake command mode.
  -L[A][H]                     = List non-advanced cached variables.
  --build <dir>                = Build a CMake-generated project binary tree.
  --install <dir>              = Install a CMake-generated project binary
                                 tree.
  --open <dir>                 = Open generated project in the associated
                                 application.
  -N                           = View mode only.
  -P <file>                    = Process script mode.
  --find-package               = Legacy pkg-config like mode.  Do not use.
  --graphviz=[file]            = Generate graphviz of dependencies, see
                                 CMakeGraphVizOptions.cmake for more.
  --system-information [file]  = Dump information about this system.
  --log-level=<ERROR|WARNING|NOTICE|STATUS|VERBOSE|DEBUG|TRACE>
                               = Set the verbosity of messages from CMake
                                 files.  --loglevel is also accepted for
                                 backward compatibility reasons.
  --log-context                = Prepend log messages with context, if given
  --debug-trycompile           = Do not delete the try_compile build tree.
                                 Only useful on one try_compile at a time.
  --debug-output               = Put cmake in a debug mode.
  --debug-find                 = Put cmake find in a debug mode.
  --trace                      = Put cmake in trace mode.
  --trace-expand               = Put cmake in trace mode with variable
                                 expansion.
  --trace-format=<human|json-v1>
                               = Set the output format of the trace.
  --trace-source=<file>        = Trace only this CMake file/module.  Multiple
                                 options allowed.
  --trace-redirect=<file>      = Redirect trace output to a file instead of
                                 stderr.
  --warn-uninitialized         = Warn about uninitialized values.
  --no-warn-unused-cli         = Don't warn about command line options.
  --check-system-vars          = Find problems with variable usage in system
                                 files.
  --profiling-format=<fmt>     = Output data for profiling CMake scripts.
                                 Supported formats: google-trace
  --profiling-output=<file>    = Select an output path for the profiling data
                                 enabled through --profiling-format.
  --help,-help,-usage,-h,-H,/? = Print usage information and exit.
  --version,-version,/V [<f>]  = Print version number and exit.
  --help-full [<f>]            = Print all help manuals and exit.
  --help-manual <man> [<f>]    = Print one help manual and exit.
  --help-manual-list [<f>]     = List help manuals available and exit.
  --help-command <cmd> [<f>]   = Print help for one command and exit.
  --help-command-list [<f>]    = List commands with help available and exit.
  --help-commands [<f>]        = Print cmake-commands manual and exit.
  --help-module <mod> [<f>]    = Print help for one module and exit.
  --help-module-list [<f>]     = List modules with help available and exit.
  --help-modules [<f>]         = Print cmake-modules manual and exit.
  --help-policy <cmp> [<f>]    = Print help for one policy and exit.
  --help-policy-list [<f>]     = List policies with help available and exit.
  --help-policies [<f>]        = Print cmake-policies manual and exit.
  --help-property <prop> [<f>] = Print help for one property and exit.
  --help-property-list [<f>]   = List properties with help available and
                                 exit.
  --help-properties [<f>]      = Print cmake-properties manual and exit.
  --help-variable var [<f>]    = Print help for one variable and exit.
  --help-variable-list [<f>]   = List variables with help available and exit.
  --help-variables [<f>]       = Print cmake-variables manual and exit.

Generators

The following generators are available on this platform (* marks default):
* Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
```

Comment: you should probably put this in your question by [editing the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67342298/edit) rather than posting as an answer...